# Simple ring that is not semi-simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

> Can someone give me an example of a simple ring that is not semi-simple ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra

Comment: Also [this DaRT search](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&L=5)

Comment: Also please read [this advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask questions. If you continue making posts that are just problem statements, and clearly aren't searching for your answer first, you're likely to face a lot of blowback, and perhaps eventually throttling of your ability to ask questions.